# How to use transaction in Spring JDBC with Guice

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring JDBC. I have created a DAO which has interface like:

```
@ImplementedBy(StuffDAOImpl.class)
public interface StuffDAO {
    void createStuff(StuffDTO stuffDTO);
    @Transactional
    void updateStuff(StuffDTO stuffDTO);
}
```

How can I config updateStuff to be transactional, for example, if there are two updates in the method:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateStuff(StuffDTO stuffDTO) {
    String query = "UPDATE stuff SET (name, username, password) = (?, ?, ?) WHERE rowid = 10";
    getJdbcTemplate().update(query, new Object[]{"John", "john", "12345"});

    // This will fail
    try {
        String wrongquery = "UPDATE tablenotexist SET (name, username, password) = (?, ?, ?) WHERE rowid = 10";
        getJdbcTemplate().update(wrongquery, new Object[]{"John", "john", "12345"});
    }catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
        // IGNORE
    }
}
```

In the above example, the second query will fail because it trying to update a table that does not exist. I think by declaring this method works as one transaction, it should serve the purpose. However it does not seem to work.

How can I make the query one also rollback if this method runs?

By the way, I use Guice instead of Spring to do DI.

Many thanks

Comment: If you're saying it's not rolling back, then the `@Transactional` is not configured correctly.

Comment: @Kevin did you end up getting somewhere with this? I'm using Guice for DI and want to use Spring JDBC + transactions

Answer (score 3):

You're using Spring JDBC, Spring transactions, but Guice for DI? Why? You're making things much more complex than needed.

Your objects are probably not Spring beans, since Spring doesn't create and inject them, so `@Transactional` has no effect: Spring doesn't create and inject the objects, so it doesn't create and inject transactional proxies, so the annotation is never used by anything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using Guice is one of the requirement from my team which is not something I can change. If Spring JDBC does not work like this way, is there any alternative to Spring JDBC you can suggest? I did considered JOOQ but it seems not provide transaction support at all.